# Gnome-Boxes "fails to start" images

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, gnome, ubuntu-18.04

Using Gnome-Boxes on Ubuntu 18.04 I consistently get an error when attempting to boot any disk image. Can anyone interpret this for me?

I am unable to make heads or tales from the troubleshooting log:

```
Broker URL: qemu+unix:///session
Domain: boxes-unknown
UUID: 63d00f48-c7da-4e74-8cb6-5e7d11f46942
Persistent: yes
Cpu time: 0
Memory: 2097152 KiB
Max memory: 5994872 KiB
CPUs: 4
State: GVIR_DOMAIN_STATE_SHUTOFF

Domain config:
------------------------------------------------------------
<domain type="kvm">
  <name>boxes-unknown</name>
  <uuid>63d00f48-c7da-4e74-8cb6-5e7d11f46942</uuid>
  <title>TrueOS-Desktop-18</title>
  <metadata>
    <boxes:gnome-boxes xmlns:boxes="https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Boxes">
      <os-state>live</os-state>
      <media>/home/$user/ISO/TrueOS-Desktop-18.03-x64-DVD.iso</media>
    </boxes:gnome-boxes>
  </metadata>
  <memory unit="KiB">2097152</memory>
  <currentMemory unit="KiB">2097152</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement="static">4</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch="x86_64" machine="pc-i440fx-bionic">hvm</type>
    <boot dev="cdrom"/>
    <boot dev="hd"/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode="custom" match="exact" check="partial">
    <model fallback="allow">SandyBridge-IBRS</model>
    <topology sockets="1" cores="2" threads="2"/>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset="utc">
    <timer name="rtc" tickpolicy="catchup"/>
    <timer name="pit" tickpolicy="delay"/>
    <timer name="hpet" present="no"/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>destroy</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled="no"/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled="no"/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm-spice</emulator>
    <disk type="file" device="disk">
      <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2" cache="writeback"/>
      <source file="/home/ev/.local/share/gnome-boxes/images/boxes-unknown"/>
      <target dev="hda" bus="ide"/>
      <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="0"/>
    </disk>
    <disk type="file" device="cdrom">
      <driver name="qemu" type="raw"/>
      <source file="/home/$user/ISO/TrueOS-Desktop-18.03-x64-DVD.iso" startupPolicy="mandatory"/>
      <target dev="hdc" bus="ide"/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="1" target="0" unit="0"/>
    </disk>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-ehci1">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x05" function="0x7"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-uhci1">
      <master startport="0"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x05" function="0x0" multifunction="on"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-uhci2">
      <master startport="2"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x05" function="0x1"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-uhci3">
      <master startport="4"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x05" function="0x2"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="0" model="pci-root"/>
    <controller type="ide" index="0">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x1"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="virtio-serial" index="0">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x06" function="0x0"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="ccid" index="0">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="2"/>
    </controller>
    <interface type="user">
      <mac address="52:54:00:de:94:8d"/>
      <model type="rtl8139"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x0"/>
    </interface>
    <smartcard mode="passthrough" type="spicevmc">
      <address type="ccid" controller="0" slot="0"/>
    </smartcard>
    <serial type="pty">
      <target type="isa-serial" port="0">
        <model name="isa-serial"/>
      </target>
    </serial>
    <console type="pty">
      <target type="serial" port="0"/>
    </console>
    <channel type="spicevmc">
      <target type="virtio" name="com.redhat.spice.0"/>
      <address type="virtio-serial" controller="0" bus="0" port="1"/>
    </channel>
    <channel type="spiceport">
      <source channel="org.spice-space.webdav.0"/>
      <target type="virtio" name="org.spice-space.webdav.0"/>
      <address type="virtio-serial" controller="0" bus="0" port="2"/>
    </channel>
    <input type="tablet" bus="usb">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="3"/>
    </input>
    <input type="mouse" bus="usb">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="4"/>
    </input>
    <input type="keyboard" bus="usb">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="5"/>
    </input>
    <input type="mouse" bus="ps2"/>
    <input type="keyboard" bus="ps2"/>
    <graphics type="spice">
      <listen type="none"/>
      <image compression="off"/>
    </graphics>
    <sound model="ac97">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x04" function="0x0"/>
    </sound>
    <video>
      <model type="qxl" ram="65536" vram="65536" vgamem="16384" heads="1" primary="yes"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x0"/>
    </video>
    <redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="6"/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="1.1"/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="1.2"/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="1.3"/>
    </redirdev>
    <hub type="usb">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="1"/>
    </hub>
    <memballoon model="virtio">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x07" function="0x0"/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

I appreciate your time.

Comment: Maybe this should be moved to askubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some more helpful messages when I tried `virt-manager` instead. Install it with: `sudo apt install virt-manager`

I did a few things before it worked, not every one may be necessary:

```
sudo apt install virt-manager
sudo systemctl enable libvirtd
sudo systemctl enable virtlogd
sudo systemctl start libvirtd
sudo systemctl start virtlogd
sudo adduser `id -un` kvm
```

and log in and out to ensure the group adding takes hold. But after this, both `gnome-boxes` and `virt-manager` managed to start images.

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts unhammer. My OS's port of adduser doesn't recognize flags -un. If possible, would you please describe what these flags do so I may translate them accordingly? (I'll upvote when I get the required reputation.)

Comment: `-un` are args to `id`; `id -un` should echo your username, and the backticks turn the output into regular string arguments. An alternative that should work is `sudo adduser "$USER" kvm` or simply write your username, e.g. `sudo adduser evan kvm`

Comment: You're a true Jedi, I can't thank you enough. So much appreciated!